# gdalinfo returns PROJCS["unnamed"] but QGIS returns the correct projection

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, proj, gdalinfo

I'm trying to understand why my gdalinfo call to a specific file returns "unnamed" for the PROJCS node.
The call looks like this: `./gdalinfo /path/to/file/dem.tif`.

Output (notice the **"unnamed"**):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /path/to/file/dem.tif
Size is 25000, 25000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-1600000.000000000000000,2350000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
```

I've tried to set both `GDAL_DATA` and `PROJ_LIB` environment variables but still, I don't get the right projection back.

Using QGIS 3.10 I get this:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3413"]]
```

Why my gdal installation doesn't recognise the projection?

If I run `./gdalsrsinfo "EPSG:3413"` the output is correct, similar to what QGIS is printing.

`listgeo` output:

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered.
Geotiff_Information:
   Version: 1
   Key_Revision: 1.0
   Tagged_Information:
      ModelTiepointTag (2,3):
         0                 0                 0
         -1600000          2350000           0
      ModelPixelScaleTag (1,3):
         2                 2                 0
      End_Of_Tags.
   Keyed_Information:
      GTModelTypeGeoKey (Short,1): ModelTypeProjected
      GTRasterTypeGeoKey (Short,1): RasterPixelIsArea
      GTCitationGeoKey (Ascii,8): "unnamed"
      GeographicTypeGeoKey (Short,1): GCS_WGS_84
      GeogCitationGeoKey (Ascii,7): "WGS 84"
      GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Angular_Degree
      GeogSemiMajorAxisGeoKey (Double,1): 6378137
      GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey (Double,1): 298.257223563
      ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey (Short,1): User-Defined
      ProjectionGeoKey (Short,1): User-Defined
      ProjCoordTransGeoKey (Short,1): CT_PolarStereographic
      ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (Short,1): Linear_Meter
      ProjNatOriginLatGeoKey (Double,1): 70
      ProjFalseEastingGeoKey (Double,1): 0
      ProjFalseNorthingGeoKey (Double,1): 0
      ProjScaleAtNatOriginGeoKey (Double,1): 1
      ProjStraightVertPoleLongGeoKey (Double,1): -45
      End_Of_Keys.
   End_Of_Geotiff.

Projection Method: CT_PolarStereographic
   ProjNatOriginLatGeoKey: 70.000000 ( 70d 0' 0.00"N)
   ProjStraightVertPoleLongGeoKey: -45.000000 ( 45d 0' 0.00"W)
   ProjScaleAtNatOriginGeoKey: 1.000000
   ProjFalseEastingGeoKey: 0.000000 m
   ProjFalseNorthingGeoKey: 0.000000 m
GCS: 4326/WGS 84
Datum: 6326/World Geodetic System 1984
Ellipsoid: 7030/WGS 84 (6378137.00,6356752.31)
Prime Meridian: 8901/Greenwich (0.000000/  0d 0' 0.00"E)
Projection Linear Units: 9001/metre (1.000000m)
```

Comment: What is your GDAL version `gdalinfo --version`?

Comment: `GDAL 2.4.2 released 2019/06/28`

Comment: GDAL 3 might show the projection differently. But have you faced any real problems? The projection parameters are the same even the name of the coordinate system is not recognized.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use GDAL 3, but I was wondering if this can be because of a wrong path to `GDAL_DATA` folder where all WKTs are stored. I've just checked now and QGIS is using `GDAL 2.4.1`.

Comment: Without having your image it is hard to tell. I wonder if the the version of libtiff library could play some role as well. If you want to do some debugging, use the "listgeo" utility and report what it prints about the coordinate system. Same information should be found with the "tiffinfo" libtiff utility, probably from tags #34735 and #34737 but they must be interpreted against the GeoTIFF specification.

Comment: @user30184 I've added the output of `listgeo` as well

Comment: It seems to me that the projection is really "unnamed" in the GeoTIFF. Perhaps QGIS, or GDAL version that QGIS is using, makes a guess by the parameters.